# forestplot has unusually large blue dot in graph

Tags: r, plot, r-forestplot

Im trying to create a `forestplot`, but the last row has a giant blue dot, instead of the small dot the other rows have. Any idea how to fix this? [these vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forestplot/vignettes/forestplot.html) are what Ive been using to create my code so far. My only thought is that the giant dot could be part of the summary (the dot seems similar) however I am not using a summary.

```
tab<-structure(list(names = c("(Intercept)", "xxx", "gender", "age"
), betas = c(54.6873516187792, 2.13385086140261, 3.26945254708992, 
             -0.305426541112294), upper = c(62.1308928551509, 4.60545786804931, 
                                            7.29686190386409, -0.112092252532382), lower = c(47.2438103824075, 
                                                                                             -0.337756145244089, -0.757956809684253, -0.498760829692206)), .Names = c("names", 
                                                                                                                                                                      "betas", "upper", "lower"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "data.frame")
###################################################################
xlab<-"xxxx"
clrs <- fpColors(box="royalblue",line="darkblue")
tabletext <-list(c(NA, tab$names),append(list(expression(beta)), sprintf("%.2f", tab$betas)))

forestplot(tabletext, 
           mean=c(NA,tab$betas),
           lower=c(NA,tab$lower),
           upper=c(NA,tab$upper),
           col=clrs,
           xlab=xlab,
           vertices = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: That solved the issue :). Please propose it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the size of the boxes to be uniform with `boxsize` or input a vector with the same length as `mean`

```
tab<-structure(list(names = c("(Intercept)", "xxx", "gender", "age"),
                    betas = c(54.6873516187792, 2.13385086140261, 3.26945254708992, -0.305426541112294),
                    upper = c(62.1308928551509, 4.60545786804931, 7.29686190386409, -0.112092252532382),
                    lower = c(47.2438103824075, -0.337756145244089, -0.757956809684253, -0.498760829692206)),
               .Names = c("names", "betas", "upper", "lower"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "data.frame")

xlab<-"xxxx"
clrs <- fpColors(box="royalblue",line="darkblue")
tabletext <-list(c(NA, tab$names),append(list(expression(beta)), sprintf("%.2f", tab$betas)))

forestplot(tabletext,
           boxsize = c(NA, .1, .1, .1, .2),
           mean=c(NA,tab$betas),
           lower=c(NA,tab$lower),
           upper=c(NA,tab$upper),
           col=clrs, xlab=xlab, vertices = TRUE)
```

or

```
forestplot(tabletext, boxsize = .1,
           mean=c(NA,tab$betas),
           lower=c(NA,tab$lower),
           upper=c(NA,tab$upper),
           col=clrs, xlab=xlab, vertices = TRUE)
```

[image]

Looking into the code for `forestplot`, you can see how the `boxsize` is calculated for you. You need to define the following values:

```
## values needed
upper <- c(NA,tab$upper)
lower <- c(NA,tab$lower)
txt_gp <- fpTxtGp()
nr <- length(upper)


## calculation in forestplot
cwidth <- (upper - lower)
cwidth[cwidth <= 0 | is.na(cwidth)] <- min(cwidth[cwidth > 0])
textHeight <- convertUnit(grobHeight(textGrob("A", gp = do.call(gpar, txt_gp$label))), unitTo = "npc", valueOnly = TRUE)
info <- 1/cwidth * 0.75
info <- info/max(info, na.rm = TRUE)
if (any(textHeight * (nr + 0.5) * 1.5 < info))
  info <- textHeight * (nr + 0.5) * 1.5 * info /
    max(info, na.rm = TRUE) + textHeight * (nr + 0.5) * 1.5/4

info
# [1]         NA 0.02402603 0.02857476 0.02594405 0.10882403
```

So now you should get the same sizes you had before

```
forestplot(tabletext,
           boxsize = info,
           mean=c(NA,tab$betas),
           lower=c(NA,tab$lower),
           upper=c(NA,tab$upper),
           col=clrs, xlab=xlab, vertices = TRUE)
```

[image]